# MySQL - Auto_increment by 10

Tags: mysql, default, auto-increment

How do I set the auto_increment column in such a way that it increments by 10 for each record insert.

For eg: Instead of the default `auto_increment` by 1,

```
insert into temptable (name) values('abc'),('def');

select * from temptable;
  id|name
  1|abc
  2|def

auto_increment by 10,
  id|name
  10|abc
  20|def
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to change the [`auto_increment_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) setting, however this would apply to all tables at once. I don't think there is a per-table increment setting.

This is usually not really a good idea to do, though. Are you looking to generate invoice numbers or something? In that case, you may be better off using a custom method that generates the next number.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why do you need that, but if you want to have this result on output you can simply multiply value by 10

Answer (score 1):

You could turn off the auto_increment, and add a trigger. Set up another table with a single value, the next id, and then set the id of an inserted row to the value of that table:

```
CREATE TABLE next (next_id int not null);
INSERT INTO next VALUES(0);

delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER update_id BEFORE INSERT ON temptable
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.id = (SELECT next_id FROM next);
    UPDATE next SET next_id = next_id + 10;
  END;
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Nice. What mySQL version does this require?

Comment: You need 5.0.2 or later for triggers.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your ids and want to enlarge them by '10 by 10', follow Nazariy's idea and use the current ids and multiply them by 10 with

`update xyourtablex set id=id*10000`

or a bigger number than your ids (if not, you will create duplicates)
and finally:

`update xyourtablex set id=id/1000`

or simply remove unique or index, multiply by 10 and add index or unique again :)