# How can I make id column increment by 10 using laravel migration functions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

How can I make id column increment by 10 using laravel migration functions.
In laravel 5.4's migration. `$table->increments('id');` creates id column to be primary key and it increments 1, 2, 3 and so on. How can I change it to increment by 10 instead 1 so I have 1, 10, 20, 30 instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046045/mysql-auto-increment-by-10

Comment: Why do you need this  however?

Comment: ClearDB's autoincrement is by 10 and it starts from 2. I am hosting the laravel app on heroku using the ClearDB as database and I get errors when seeding